# Quality Over Quantities

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, number-sequence

[image]

Your final answer will be a number (or maybe not?)

6.1482925535194332784626433,
15,
70,
5388440228181184467208035634811703511875,
45,
1207432478148385373947988/38313917,
15,
70,
?

Comment: oh hey that's me

Comment: Pretty bold to label your own puzzle as high-quality :)

Comment: Technically he didn't :P

Comment: Looks mind-blowing at first sight but in fact, this is an excellent 'in-your-face' to Deusovi.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

6.1482925535194332784626433

> This number appears to be the same as pi (truncated to 26 places), but with eight digits changed. That 26 is suspicious - looking at the changed digits, they're all between one and eight. Taking the *n*th letter, where *n* is the position of the digit changed to *k*, gives **LEONHARD**.

15, 70

> These numbers look like "IS TO".

5388440228181184467208035634811703511875

> This number prime factorizes as $3^6\cdot 5^4\cdot 7^8\cdot 11^7\cdot 47^3\cdot 71^1\cdot 73^5\cdot 83^2$. Those exponents range from 1 to 8, and the primes are pretty small. Sort by exponent, then take each prime's index in the list of primes (2 maps to A, 3 to B, 5 to C, 7 to D...), and you get TWO CUBED, which is naturally a clue for **EIGHT**.

45

> 45 looks like "AS" in a similar way to how 15 and 70 yielded IS and TO.

1207432478148385373947988/38313917

> Dividing this out gives 31514200914210504.0825... . Taking pairs of digits and converting to letters gives "CONTINUED", a hint to look at the continued fraction. The continued fraction for this number is [31514200914210504; 12, 9, 11, 5, 2, 12, 15, 15], and converting those to letters gives "LIKE BLOO", a hint to the word **IMAGINARY** (a reference to Bloo from the cartoon [Foster's Home for Imaginary Friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foster%27s_Home_for_Imaginary_Friends))

15, 70

> IS, TO again.

?

> LEONHARD means Euler's number, **e**.
>  IMAGINARY means the imaginary unit, **i**.
>  That means we have "**e** is to **EIGHT** as **i** is to ???", and the answer is **INFINITY**, another "number" starting with its corresponding letter.

Comment: If it takes 13 hours to get to a partial answer at least you can say the puzzle is nice and hard ;)

Comment: So…?  E is to B as I is to ?

Comment: I think the intended interpretation is LEONHARD is to EIGHT as IMAGINARY is to ?, in which case it's NINE (number of letters).

Comment: @Ankoganit I was more thinking about 3-8, 1-6 or E-B, I-G and that 9 fits it too, so answer is g/G/6/9? Probably